# max_binlog_size & log-bin size

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

I have a problem with full disk

```
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1073741982 2012-07-03 18:14 mysql-bin.000034
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1073741890 2012-07-04 14:39 mysql-bin.000035
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1073741988 2012-07-05 09:16 mysql-bin.000036
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1073741964 2012-07-06 00:04 mysql-bin.000037
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1073741974 2012-07-06 21:45 mysql-bin.000038
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1073741923 2012-07-07 19:05 mysql-bin.000039
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql  356167680 2012-07-07 23:47 mysql-bin.000040
```

my.cnf:

```
max_binlog_size = 1073741824
log-bin = mysql-bin
max_relay_log_size = 1G
relay_log_space_limit = 2G
```

mysql is creating files mysql-bin.xxxxx and my disk is full after several days.

How to make mysql to delete old logs ?

Comment: SET GLOBAL expire_logs_days=2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In addition to setting `expire_logs_days` you can run a command immediately to purge old logs:

`mysql> PURGE BINARY LOGS TO 'mysql-bin.000039';`

Make sure no slaves are reading from logs you're trying to purge, or you will break replication.

See the [MySQL Reference Manual: Binary logs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/purge-binary-logs.html)

Comment: minor correction - it's expire_logs_days (notice 'logs' instead of 'log') - see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_expire_logs_days for more detail